# How to bind multiple keys with hotkey.bind?

Tags: hammerspoon

like when I type "aq", to output "Ask a public question"

```
hs.hotkey.bind({}, "aq", function()
  hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("Ask a public question")
end)
```

Comment: Why not just use the **macOS** _built-in text replacement_ feature... **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**  Also have a look at: [Replace text and punctuation in documents on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/10.15/mac/10.15)